# QTimer in a template class

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I have a template class, in my case a state-machine class, so that I can construct it with any of my class-types such that it can call member functions using a function table with pointers to the member functions (kind of like a call-back).

It processes an event by looking the event up in a table (where state and event match) and then calling the pointer to the appropriate function.

This is all working. What I want to do next is add a timer so that when the timer expires it calls the processEvent() function with event code "TIMER_EXPIRED".

The problem for me is that in Qt template classes don't appear to be supported for slots/signals. So, I can add a QTimer, but I can't connect it up or define/emit slots/signals.

My alternative is to implement the timer in the class that owns the state machine, which is fine, but then I have to do this for all classes that use the state machine class.

So I am not really sure which direction to go next, is there some trickery I can use to get around this issue?

I would add example code, but since I have not been able to implement the QTimer within the state machine class, because I can't inherit QObject, there is no code to show yet :(

Comment: You can use lambdas instead of slots.

Comment: @SaZ, I am not 100% up on lambda functions, but I still can't see how they can help me implement a QTimer in my class, can you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambdas can be utilized this way:

```
#pragma once

#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>

template< class T > class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        _timer.setInterval(1000);
        // connecting the signal to the lambda
        // that will call the desired function:
        QObject::connect(&_timer, &QTimer::timeout,
                &_timer, [&](){
            theFunctionThatNeedToBeRunOnTimer();
        });
        _timer.start();
    }

    void theFunctionThatNeedToBeRunOnTimer()
    {
        qDebug() << "Timer ticked!";
    }

private:
    QTimer _timer;
};
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work (compile), I don't quite get it though!, How does the lambda translate into a "slot" type function? Thanks : )

Comment: @code_fodder, it doesn't, this syntax of `connect` was introduced specially for the case of binding a signal to a lambda or a functor. Note the third parameter, which is used as the context for the lambda. If the object passed as the third parameter is destroyed, the signal will not be emitted. More info [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-5).

Comment: ahhh, I see, thanks very much : )   .. so in theory you can do the same trick with just a functor (and not necessarily a lambda?

Comment: @code_fodder, yes, you can use a functor too, but using a lambda is more concise.

Comment: @code_fodder You can `connect` to any method of any class, in fact. The class you connect to doesn't have to be a `QObject`, and even on a `QObject` it doesn't have to be declared as a slot.

Comment: @KubaOber ah... so in SingerOfTheFall's example code, how would you connect his timer->timeout() signal to theFunctionThatNeedToBeRunOnTimer() without lambda? I have tried this in my code and have not been able to get that to work...

Comment: @code_fodder `connect` to [`std::bind(&Class::method, object)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). In this case, `connect(&_timer, &QTimer::timeout, std::bind(&MyClass::theFunctionThatNeedToBeRunOnTimer, this))`. Don't forget to `#include <functional>`

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks very much!